# Add class to all input types except button,sumit and reset using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Want to add css class to all form elements except input:type=button,submit,reset.

i used this jquery code.

```
$("input").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("form-control");
});

$("select").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("form-control");
});
```

i want to exclude submit,button and reset. I Know how to add manually types of input in jquery each function but i want to know if anyway to exclude some types using jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude button and reset buttons using [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/), [button-selector](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) and [reset-selector](http://api.jquery.com/reset-selector/)

```
$("input, select, textare").not(':button, :reset')
```

Answer (score 3):

[Not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) is what you need i think